# Find $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ such that $\mathbf{x}^* \mathbf{M} \mathbf{y}=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Let $\mathbf{x}$ be a $k \times 1$ complex vector and $\mathbf{y}$ be an $n \times  1$ complex vector.  We define $\mathbf{M}$ as a $k \times n$ complex matrix. Assume that $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are of unit norm.  Aslo assume that $\mathbf{M}$ is full rank.
I am intersted in finding vectors $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ such that

$$\mathbf{x}^* \mathbf{M} \mathbf{y}=0,$$
where $\mathbf{x}^*$ stands for the conjugate transpose of $\mathbf{x}$.

What are the possible ways to compute these vectors ?
Is it possible to know the number of pairs of vectors that satisfy the above condition ?

Comment: If $x,y$ satisfy the conditions, so do $cx,dy$ for any complex numbers $c,d$ of modulus 1. So if there's one pair of vectors that work, then there's continuum many.

Comment: Pick any unit vector $y\in\mathbb C^n$. Let $z=My\in\mathbb C^k$. If $z=0$, $x$ can be any unit vector in $\mathbb C^k$. If not, the vectors orthogonal to $z$ form a $(k-1)$-dimensional subspace. Let $x$ be any unit vector in this subspace; for example, take an arbitrary $\tilde x$ which is not a scalar multiple of $z$, project out its component parallel to $z$,  and normalize it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1) Case $k \neq n.$**

We may assume that $k<n$ where $k$ is the number of rows of $M$ ($M$ is "landscape") (otherwise, it suffices to transpose-conjugate relationship **$x^*My=0$**.)

As $M$ is full rank, it means that its rank is $min(k,n)=k$.

Therefore, the $k+1$ first columns $C_1,C_2,\cdots C_{k+1}$ of $M$ are not independent.

As a consequence, there exist a linear combination (with not all coefficients zero) : $$\ \sum_{i=1}^{k+1}a_iC_i=0$$
that we extend in this way :

$$\tag{1}\sum_{i=1}^{n}a_iC_i=0$$

by taking $0$ for the (possible) missing coefficients.

(1) can be written under the form:

$$\tag{2}\pmatrix{m_{11} & \cdots & \cdots & m_{1n}\\
\vdots &&& \vdots \\ m_{k1} & \cdots & \cdots & m_{kn}}\pmatrix{a_1\\a_2\\ \vdots \\a_{n}}=\pmatrix{0\\0\\ \vdots \\0}$$

It suffices then to multiply both sides of (2) by **any** row vector **$x$** to fulfill the desired condition.

---

**2) Case $n=k.$**

Let us solve this case in two (complex) dimensions, in order to simplify its presentation. The general case is completely similar. Expanding

$$\tag{3} \pmatrix{x_1^* & x_2^*}\pmatrix{m_{11} & m_{12}\\
m_{21} & m_{22}}\pmatrix{y_1\\y_2}=0$$

we obtain

$$\tag{4}x_1^*(m_{11}y_1+m_{12}y_2)+x_2^*(m_{21}y_1+m_{22}y_2)=0,$$
one sees that in (4), for any choice of $\pmatrix{x_1^* & x_2^*}$, it suffices to take for $(y_1,y_2)$ "the" (or "a") solution to the linear system:

$$\tag{5}\cases{m_{11}y_1+m_{12}y_2=x_2^*\\m_{21}y_1+m_{22}y_2=-x_1^*}$$

which is known to always have either one solution or an infinite number of solutions because $M$ is full-rank.